# PySide / Qt Import Error

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyside

I'm trying to import PySide / Qt into Python like so and get the follow error:

```
from PySide import QtCore

ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtCore.so, 2): Library not loaded: libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtCore.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I'm running/installed via:

- Mac OSX 10.9.4 Mavericks
- Homebrew Python 2.7
- Homebrew installed Qt
- Pip installed PySide

The file libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib is located in the same path as the QtCore.so file listed in the error message.

All my searches for this particular problem have yielded people trying to package these libraries as part of an app, which I am not doing. I am just trying to run it on my system and yet have this problem. For troubleshooting an app, people suggested oTool; not sure if it is helpful here, but this is the output when I run oTool:

```
otool -L QtCore.so 
QtCore.so:
    libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib (compatibility version 1.2.0, current version 1.2.2)
    libshiboken-python2.7.1.2.dylib (compatibility version 1.2.0, current version 1.2.2)
    /usr/local/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.6)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you actually trying to use both PySide and PyQt in the same app? Because they don't play nicely together.

Comment: Also, are you sure you're using the Homebrew Python 2.7 and its pip consistently, and not using Apple's pre-installed Python 2.7 anywhere?

Comment: Yes, Pip for Homebrew Python. I've installed many a package with no issue.

Comment: And you're right, I'm not using PyQt, just PySide and having issues with Qt. I'll fix the title

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, the installer is somewhat broken, because the output from oTool should report a full path to the library (the path should be changed by the Pyside installer using install_name_tool).

Instead of going mad understanding what part of the installer is broken, I suggest you define:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/your/path/to/pyside/libraries
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

This will force the executable loader to scan for libraries into the path you supply too, even it's not configured by the linker.

Comment: How do you find the path to the Pyside libraries?

Comment: @jkabrg you can do: "find `dirname \`which python\``/.. -name *pyside*so*" . That gets the path to python, goes to the main directory, then uses that as a path for `find`

Comment: @Leonardo Bernardini The exported variable should be "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" or it won't work on some macs.

Answer (score 13):

if you watch this , you're question will be fixed:
https://github.com/pyside/packaging/blob/master/setuptools/templates/pyside_postinstall.py

`pyside_postinstall.py -install`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solved the issue after running your script in the virtualenv path.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't work for me.  After a seemingly successful `pip install PySide`, This script gives me an error "The PySide package not installed: None"

Comment: The master branch does no longer contain the file linked to above. Here you find the one which worked for me: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PySide/pyside-setup/1.2.2/pyside_postinstall.py

Comment: If you run into an error like "RuntimeError: install_name_tool -change libpyside...returned code 1" after you ran `pyside_postinstall.py -install`, add `sudo` before it and re-run can solve it.

Comment: As of version [1.2.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide#id3) (released 2015-10-12), it should no longer be necessary to run the post install script. If you are still getting the error mentioned by OP, this likely isn't the solution.

Comment: @Chrispy https://github.com/pyside/packaging/blob/master/setuptools/templates/pyside_postinstall.py

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, and I resolved it by manually using `otool -L` (as seen in the question) and `install_name_tool` to update the paths.

```
install_name_tool -change @rpath/libshiboken.cpython-34m.1.2.dylib /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PySide/libshiboken.cpython-34m.1.2.dylib /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PySide/QtCore.so

install_name_tool -change @rpath/libpyside.cpython-34m.1.2.dylib /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PySide/libpyside.cpython-34m.1.2.dylib /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PySide/QtCore.so
```

I had to do this for several files in the PySide directory before the script would run.

This blog post is a nice reference: http://thecourtsofchaos.com/2013/09/16/how-to-copy-and-relink-binaries-on-osx/

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution [here](http://www.danielelliott.co.uk/2016/06/18/fixing-pip-installation-of-pyside-in-osx/#comment-139)

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python[version]/site-packages/PySide
```

for python 3.5 this would be

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PySide
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, on Mavericks using a Brew-installed Qt and virtual environment.

I had to `brew reinstall Qt`

Then run the `pyside_postinstall.py -install`

See here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/27898