# PySide install errors - python 2.7 - QT5 - macOS Sierra

Tags: python, qt5, pyside, macos-sierra

I've spent hours (days) trying to install `PySide` on a macOS sierra with no success. I read and followed many explanations given by google search, including threads on stackoverflow.

My latest attempt is using pip:

```
pip install PySide
```

But I'm getting a bunch of errors:
The 1st one is:

```
Qt QTGUI library not found.
Qt QTXML library not found.
Qt QTCORE library not found.
CMake Error at ApiExtractor/CMakeLists.txt:82 (qt4_add_resources):
Unknown CMake command "qt4_add_resources".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/private/var/folders/jn/_85_tmmn3bjgrfdprd_l2c640000gn/T/pip-build-rjWn4w/PySide/pyside_build/py2.7-qt5.8.0-64bit-release/shiboken/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
error: Error configuring shiboken

----------------------------------------
Failed building wheel for PySide
Running setup.py clean for PySide
Failed to build PySide
```

And the last one is:

> Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/jn/_85_tmmn3bjgrfdprd_l2c640000gn/T/pip-build-rjWn4w/PySide/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /var/folders/jn/_85_tmmn3bjgrfdprd_l2c640000gn/T/pip-1xbkki-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/var/folders/jn/_85_tmmn3bjgrfdprd_l2c640000gn/T/pip-build-rjWn4w/PySide/

Is this enough information to explain the problem?
I guess my question is (are): what am I doing wrong? How can I make this work? (install Pyside for python 2.7, qt5, macOS sierra.)

Please let me know if I need to give other info in order to be helped in some way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Stefan

[EDIT] links problem after brew install qt5 cmake libxslt libxml2

```
Warning: qt is a keg-only and another version is linked to opt.
Use `brew install --force` if you want to install this version
Warning: cmake-3.8.0 already installed
Warning: libxslt is a keg-only and another version is linked to opt.
Use `brew install --force` if you want to install this version
Warning: libxml2 is a keg-only and another version is linked to opt.
Use `brew install --force` if you want to install this version
stefan-mbcn:export_hook stefan$ brew install --force qt5 cmake libxslt libxml2
Warning: qt-5.8.0_2 already installed, it's just not linked.
Warning: cmake-3.8.0 already installed
Warning: libxslt-1.1.29 already installed, it's just not linked.
Warning: libxml2-2.9.4_2 already installed, it's just not linked.
stefan-mbcn:export_hook stefan$
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already checked [this thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41782161/3659824), where is stated that macOS sierra is not supported. Still you can try minigeeks solution. Also have a look at the [wiki of pyside](https://github.com/PySide/pyside2/wiki/Dependencies). If you did not already try, install homebrew and  do the following:

```
brew install qt5 cmake libxslt libxml2
```

Comment: Thanks @LaughU. I did read this thread and and tried the command you mention, but i'm getting 'links' error that i don't know how to fix exactly without breaking anything else.
I edited the original question and added the links part.